# Custom PC Shop DB

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to make a Custom PC Shop database with MySQL where users are able to customize their PC's and select the pieces they like to build one. I am having a little bit of trouble trying to come with the proper structure of the tables for how to check whether a product is compatible with one another or not?
I would appreciate any guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like classic many-to-many relationship. What I would do is to create a compatibility table which hosts all the pairs of IDs of compatible items. Then every time you need to check whether 2 particular items are compatible (or if need to present user with the choice of the items compatible with the one he has already chosen) do join on this table.